# Bash shell script printing out rows but not colums

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my bash shell script. When ran my matrix file takes an argument "dims" and then a file called matrix one (m1) that is just a list of numbers. I have to print out the number of rows and columns in said file. It prints out rows but columns it prints out zero. Can anyone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
elif [[ "$1" = dims && $# -eq 2 && -e "$2" && -r "$2" ]]
then
echo "we are reading this from a file"
while read -a line
do
NUM_OF_COLS="${#matrixarray[@]}"
((NUM_OF_ROWS++))
done <$2
echo "$NUM_OF_ROWS $NUM_OF_COLS"
exit 0

esle
echo "System failed sorry" >&2
exit 1
fi
  ;;
```

Comment: if anyone needs help with this I figured it out. While read -a line needs to be while read -a matrixarray

Comment: You have a few typos like `esle`. Also I'd suggest indenting your code to make it easier to read. There's no need for `-e $2` if you're using `-r $2` afterwards.

Comment: @AndrewWhite You should just delete your question since it's just based on a typo, not useful to anyone else.

Comment: It also looks like the code is incomplete.

Comment: for future reference, include sample input data, current/wrong output, and the expected/correct output